# Check if first character in string is quotation mark

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios6, nsstring

I wrote a code that would split up content from a string, check if the content has quotation mark as first character, and then combining them back into two strings: 
one that starts with quotation marks and one that don't. I have the following code but when I run it, it doesn't seem to detect quotation mark.

```
NSArray *detailTextLabelContentArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Some",@"Good",@"Stuff",@"\"Lazy\"", nil];
for (NSInteger index = 0; [detailTextLabelContentArray count] > index; index++)
{
    if ([[detailTextLabelContentArray objectAtIndex:index] substringToIndex:1] != @"\"")
    {
        if (index == 0)
        {
            detailTextLabelContent = [[detailTextLabelContentArray objectAtIndex:index] substringToIndex:1];
        }
        else
        {
            detailTextLabelContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@; %@",detailTextLabelContent,detailTextLabelContent = [[detailTextLabelContentArray objectAtIndex:index] substringToIndex:1]];
        }
    }
}
NSLog(detailTextLabelContent);
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `!=` or any other equality operators to compare `NSString`s. Use `-[NSString isEqualToString:]` instead:

```
![[[detailTextLabelContentArray objectAtIndex:index] substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"\""]
```

The equality operators compare only pointer equality, not object equality.

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSString *str=@"\"hello";
 NSRange range={0,1};
[[str substringWithRange:range] isEqualToString:@"\""];
```